# strange error while formatting a string from published value

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Formatting the published value in my model (as computed property) I've got very strange error

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = 0.0
    var progress: String {
        String(format: "%.2f %%", value) // Expression type 'String' is ambiguous without more context
    }
}
```

I found a "workaround"

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = 0.0
    var progress: String {
        String(format: "%.2f %%", value * 1) // No error :-)
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Xcode 11.3.1 Solution

Just surround your expression in parentheses, like so:

```
String(format: "%.2f %%", (value))
```

#### Xcode 11.4 Solution

***This bug was apparently fixed in Xcode 11.4!!***

No code changes are needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've discover the same between ... It is nice to see such a qualified answer!!! It is worth to say, that the last works because String is creating for each parameter

Comment: @user3441734 You're welcome! This was a fun nut to crack!

Comment: I did see String there :-), sorry!

Comment: from docs "Declaring conformance to the CVarArg protocol for types defined outside the standard library is not supported."

Comment: Jacob, nice to know it will be solved in next release, but the workaround you mentioned doesn't work. String.init(format:arguments:) it is init(format: String, arguments: [CVarArg])

Comment: most likely you means String(format:) with parameter (value), it could be confusing for somebody ... please edit your answer.